# Selection of security rules for multiple network security groups (nsg)

Tags: azure

Let's say I have an azure VM (in ARM) with a NIC that is associated to multiple NSGs. Also, the IP of the NIC is in a subnet, with multiple NSGs. I'd like to know, how the selection of security rules for inbound traffic works for:

- Inbound traffic from the same subnet.
- Inbound traffic from a different subnet (same vnet)
- Inbound traffic from the internet.

I'm also interested in your opinion w.r.t. the usefullness of such a setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to say is that a NIC can only be associated with one NSG at a time and a subnet can only be associated with one NSG at a time.

Lets pretend you have a VM with a single NIC and a it is connected to a Subnet and they both have NSGs associated with them.

For Inbound traffic the NSG associated with the Subnet is checked first and the traffic must be able to pass its inbound rules. If the traffic passes the inbound rules of the NSG associated with the Subnet then the NSG associated with the NIC of the VM is checked, the traffic would have to pass the rules of this NSG before being passed in the VM.

for outbound traffic same thing just in reverse. Also note that Host based firewalls might still block traffic regardless of what the NSGs say.

You can find more information here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-pportal

Comment: You're right. The webinterface is a bit inconsistent: When you try to associate a NIC to a second NSG, the already associated NICs are greyed out. In contrast, associating a subnet to a second NSG 'works'. It's just that the subnet is also removed from the previous NSG. ... which I didn't notice.